# Batch printing document loaded in Browser Control in C# WinForm

Tags: c#-4.0, printing, webbrowser-control, batch-processing

Here is what I'm trying to do:

1. I have a simple form with `WebBrowser` control on it along with Print (`ShowPrintDialog()`) and Print Preview (`ShowPrintPreviewDialog()`) buttons,
2. On opening of the form, I load an external HTML document.
3. User prints the document using provided print/print preview buttons.

Now the flow is manual, but **is there any way I can automate this by loading series of documents into the browser control and directly send it to printing queue without any user intervention?** I'm not sure if its technically a batch printing as I'm not sending file to be printed directly to the print queue. Note that Browser control is in the picture here since printed document is essentially WYSWYG as on Browser control.

Comment: I don't understand if you necessarily need that the documents will be loaded into the webBrowser

Comment: @trippino: Yes it is needed since the document has some JS code on it which renders a Chart, that's why I mentioned its WYSWYG in the printed document. While I'm okay by launching and closing the form programmatically (let the screen flicker, I'm okay with it), it is mainly about sending the document from browser control directly to the printing queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the `Print()` method of `WebBrowser` if you put it into the DocumentCompleted event:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Print();
}
```

After the print you can pass to the next page to print:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Print();
    webBrowser1.Navigate(nextPage());
}
```

The only thing you need now is to make the `WebBrowser` navigate to the first page (you can set it on the constructor of the form)

Comment: Is it okay to dispose the form having this browser control while documents are in the print queue?

Comment: Surprisingly it didn't! I had a loop iterating over all reports, for each report; sending it to browser control, window shows up, I call `.print()` and immediately dispose the window. Works absolutely fine.

Comment: ah ok, I thought you wanted to dispose the form where there is the loop